# python create dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list in python

```
 ['Claudius II Gothicus', 'Antoninianus', None, ' Mediolanum']
```

It's possible to convert to a dictionary like this:

```
{
 "Herscher": "Claudius II Gothicus",
 "Fundort": "Antoninianus",
 "Material": "None",
"Art": "Mediolanum",

}
```

Comment: `"None"` must become a string too…?!

Comment: @deceze actually not

Comment: and `"Herscher"`, `"Fundort"`, etc. are random keywords?

Comment: `dict(zip(['Herscher', ...], the_list))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result_dict = {}
for i in range(len(your_list)):
    if i == 0:
        result_dict["Herscher"] = your_list[i]
    elif i == 1:
        result_dict["Fundort"] = your_list[i]
    elif i == 2:
        result_dict["Material"] = your_list[i]
    elif i == 3:
        result_dict["Art"] = your_list[i]
print(result_dict)
```

Output :

```
{
 "Herscher": "Claudius II Gothicus",
 "Fundort": "Antoninianus",
 "Material": "None",
"Art": "Mediolanum",

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
keys = ["Herscher", "Fundort", "Material", "Art"]
values = ['Claudius II Gothicus', 'Antoninianus', None, ' Mediolanum']
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = ['Claudius II Gothicus', 'Antoninianus', None, ' Mediolanum']
keys = ["Herscher", "Fundort", "Material", "Art"]
obj = {}
for idx,key in enumerate(keys):
    obj[key] = values[idx]
```